# Moving Older Version Files to another folder via a script

Tags: scripting, date, time

I am trying to find a way of getting my cmd script to look through my folder, find the older versions of the pdf docs in the folder and move them to another folder called older versions.

Problem I am having is the name of the file changes with the version. IE 
DE-321-DLS-R04.pdf has become DE-321-DLS-R05.pdf

I am not to sure where to start. I have seen scripts that use the date but filenames are different.

Please help.

Comment: I guess the main problem here is how to tell if two files are two versions of the same document or two independent documents. Do you have some file name convention? e.g. all versions are named by appending `-Rxx`.

Comment: Is the first part of the name always the same for one document and were the old versions created before the new versions were added?

Answer (score 2):

Maybe something like this:

```
find . -name 'DE-321-DLS-R*.pdf' | sort -r | sed '1 d' | xargs mv -t "older versions"
```

**Explanation:**

- `find . -name 'DE-321-DLS-R*.pdf'` lists all PDF files in the current directory that begin with `DE-321-DLS-R`.
- `sort -r` sorts the list of files in **reverse** order.
- `sed '1 d'` outputs all lines of input except the first one.
- `xargs mv -t "older versions"` invokes `mv` with the output of the previous `sed` command as arguments, and tells `mv` to move all arguments to the directory `older versions`.

**Example:**

```
$ ls -1
DE-321-DLS-R00.pdf
DE-321-DLS-R01.pdf
DE-321-DLS-R02.pdf
DE-321-DLS-R03.pdf
DE-321-DLS-R04.pdf
DE-321-DLS-R05.pdf
$ mkdir "older versions"
$ find . -name 'DE-321-DLS-R*.pdf' | sort -r | sed '1 d' |
xargs mv -t "older versions"
$ ls -1
DE-321-DLS-R05.pdf
older versions
$ ls -1 "older versions"
DE-321-DLS-R00.pdf
DE-321-DLS-R01.pdf
DE-321-DLS-R02.pdf
DE-321-DLS-R03.pdf
DE-321-DLS-R04.pdf
```

Comment: nice explanation

Comment: Hi Thomas. That looks like it would work will, I will give it a go when I get back to work in the morning. Thanks very much.

Comment: I cant seem to get this to work.

Comment: @Simon Can you describe the issues you are having with the oneliner in more detail?

Comment: Thomas. I am writing this in a script and have the files on my K drive. I have got the dir K:\ "find de-321-dls" /i | /r but the rest does not seem to work.

Comment: Thomas. I am writing this in a script and have the files on my K drive. I have got the dir K:\ "find de-321-dls" /i | /r but the rest does not seem to work.Nothing happens in the script, the sed '1 d' seems to do nothing as does the xargs mv -t command.  I am doing this on windows 7. Not to sure if that makes a difference.

Comment: @Simon This is a question site for Linux, FreeBSD and other Unix-like operating systems. I've flagged the question to be migrated to [StackOverflow](http://stackoverflow.com/). That is the proper site for questions on Windows scripting.

Comment: @Thomas. Cool, sorry could not find any other sites apart from this one for scripting. Will seek answers from that site.

Answer (score 0):

**Generate some documents for testing:**

```
$ mkdir temp
$ cd temp
$ touch aaa-R00.pdf  aaa-R01.pdf aaa-R02.pdf  bbb-R19.pdf bbb-R20.pdf
$ ls | sort -r

bbb-R20.pdf
bbb-R19.pdf
aaa-R02.pdf
aaa-R01.pdf
aaa-R00.pdf
```

Look! *bbb-R20.pdf* and *aaa-R02.pdf* are lastest versions, other should be moved.

**Copy paste this script to your terminal, that mark outdate document as 'outdate'**

```
for doc in $(ls | grep 'R[0-9][0-9].pdf$' | sort -r); do
  name=${doc%%[0-9][0-9].pdf}

  if [[ "$name" != "$last" ]]; then
    echo $doc latest
  else
    echo $doc outdate
  fi
  last=$name
done
```

result:

```
bbb-R20.pdf latest
bbb-R19.pdf outdate
aaa-R02.pdf latest
aaa-R01.pdf outdate
aaa-R00.pdf outdate
```

**For your question, you can replace "echo $doc outdate" to "mv $doc path/to/outdate/"**